# Typescript: index signature on class properties

Tags: typescript

I am getting an error about index signatures when trying to dynamically access my static and instantiated class properties. I've found a lot of people talking about this error online, but I've not yet been able to fix the issue.

I was able to reproduce the issue on a simple class:

```
interface MyClassInterface {
  name: string;
  getInstanceProperty( propertyName: string ): string;
  getStaticProperty( propertyName: string ): number;
}

class MyClass implements MyClassInterface {

  public name: string;

  private static age: number;

  public constructor( theName: string, theAge: number ) {

    this.name = theName;
    MyClass.age = theAge;

  }

  public getInstanceProperty( propertyName: string ): string {

    return this[propertyName];
    // Typescript error:
    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'MyClass' has no index signature.

  }

  public getStaticProperty( propertyName: string ): number {

    return MyClass[propertyName];
    // Typescript error:
    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof MyClass' has no index signature.

  }

}

const myClass = new MyClass( "John", 35 );

console.log(
  myClass.getInstanceProperty( "name" ),
  myClass.getStaticProperty( "age" )
); // Outputs "John 35" in the console
```

I found that it is possible to avoid the error in getInstanceProperty() by adding a type information inside of the class as follows:

```
class MyClass implements MyClassInterface {
  [key: string]: any;

  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to add this in the class interface? I haven't managed to do it yet.
I suppose that I need a similar modification somewhere for the static properties, but I don't know how to do it. Any idea?

I have reproduced this code in the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyClassInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20getInstanceProperty%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20getStaticProperty%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20implements%20MyClassInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20private%20static%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20constructor(%20theName%3A%20string%2C%20theAge%3A%20number%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20theName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20MyClass.age%20%3D%20theAge%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20getInstanceProperty(%20propertyName%3A%20string%20)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this%5BpropertyName%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20getStaticProperty(%20propertyName%3A%20string%20)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20MyClass%5BpropertyName%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myClass%20%3D%20new%20MyClass(%20%22John%22%2C%2035%20)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%0D%0A%20%20myClass.getInstanceProperty(%20%22name%22%20)%2C%0D%0A%20%20myClass.getStaticProperty(%20%22age%22%20)%0D%0A)%3B). You just need to enable the noImplicitAny option to show the errors.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been an [open issue on TypeScript's GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6480) for a few years around this. It doesn't seem to be possible to have a static index signature currently.

I think the only way around this limitation is to help the compiler out by letting it know that your class has a static index signature by using a type assertion like below.

```js
interface Indexable {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class MyClass {
    ...
    public getStaticProperty( propertyName: string ): number {
      return (MyClass as Indexable)[propertyName];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot, it's going to be a great help. I haven't played with type assertions yet, but maybe I should look into it. It seems to be quite a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be:

```typescript
class MyClass {

    public static myMethod(variable:any):string{

    }

}

interface Indexable {
    [key:string]:any;
}

export const MyExportedClass = MyClass as Indexable;
```